# Can invite module work for existing users?

Tags: 7, users

I'm using UR and invite module.  I'm trying to make it so you can "friend" "existing" users.  I don't know why Invite is only set for e-mail address invites for just non-users.  I want A FB style "friend" request.  Is there a way to fanangle this though these modules? Or, do I have to go in another direction with it?

Comment: Are you sure you're using [Invite](http://drupal.org/project/invite) in Drupal 7? It doesn't seem to have even a dev version out there for 7.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/20967/release

Comment: Could you even accomplish something like this in 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Invite](http://drupal.org/project/invite) module serves to invite those who are not yet existing users to become ones. That's why you cannot use it to invite existing users.

Anyway, when using UR, at existing user's public profile, there's a *Become USERNAME's friend* link which you can use to befriend an existing user. This is an equivalent of the Facebook *Add Friend* button.

With the UR's `user_relationship_invites` module enabled, you can give users the option of specifying a relationship when inviting new users, e.g. friend. Together with the [Contact Importer](http://drupal.org/project/contact_importer) this would be an equivalent of the Facebook *Find friends* page.